# how to link multiple port in html when send data

Tags: html, node.js

now, page routing using port 3000 like this.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const HOST = "0.0.0.0";

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "pages")));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html");
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

When I request below get method, then data sended to 3000 port.

```
<form action="/user" method="get">
  User name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="test">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to do request using port 3001. 
how to decide port?

Comment: Change the value of the `PORT` variable…?

Answer (score 0):

The [port number](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.3) is part of the authority component of the URL. You can only change it by explicitly specifying the the whole authority.

You can either use an absolute URL or a scheme relative URL.

```
action="//localhost:3001/user"
action="http://localhost:3001/user"
```